# How may I reduce the size of a symbol to match some other symbol?

Tags: symbols, scaling

How may I reduce the size of `$\Sigma$` so that it aligns with, e.g., the lowercase letter `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resize:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\rSigma}{\mathpalette\reducecapital\Sigma}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reducecapital}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1a$}%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$a\rSigma_{a\rSigma}$

\end{document}
```

With `\mathpalette` we can get the expected result also in subscripts and superscripts (or text fractions and so on).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How may I adjust the size?

Comment: @Sapiens What do you mean?

Comment: @Sapiens: where egreg wrote `\sbox\z@{$#1a$}%`, replace the letter `a` with the symbol you want to rescaling to match.